# Rails/RSpec - write rspec testing for Flash Notice

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

Below is my Helper method for displaying flash notice.

I want to write Rspec Testing so How can I write.

Please Help me.

```
def flash_type_to_alert(type)
    case type
    when :notice
      return :success
    when :info
      return :info
    when :alert
      return :warning
    when :error
      return :danger
    else
      return type
    end
end
```

Thanks, In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would improve your helper removing all `return` statements and removing the case `info`.

```
def flash_type_to_alert(type)
  case type
  when :notice
    :success
  when :alert
    :warning
  when :error
    :danger
  else
    type
  end
end
```

The tests you need would be something like that:

```
describe "flash_type_to_alert(type)" do
  it "defines the success class when flash notice is set" do
    expect(helper.flash_type_to_alert(:notice)).to eq(:success)
  end
  it "defines the warning class when flash alert is set" do
    expect(helper.flash_type_to_alert(:alert)).to eq(:warning)
  end
  it "defines the danger class when flash error is set" do
    expect(helper.flash_type_to_alert(:error)).to eq(:danger)
  end
  it "defines the given class when any other flash is set" do
    expect(helper.flash_type_to_alert(:info)).to eq(:info)
  end
end
```